# eslint parsing error with vuejs and typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

I have a vue project with an interface defined like

```
export interface Task {
id?: number;
title: string;
description: string;
assigned?: string | null;
dueDate?: Date | null;
completedDate?: Date | null;
}
```

in my .ts file.
and eslint is highlighting the word interface and saying "**Parsing error: unexpected token interface**".

The code runs perfectly ok, but I am just trying to remove all the eslint errors. Relevant part of my package.json file is

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.11",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.19"
  }
```

Has anyone come across this problem? I had assumed it was a version mismatch between typescript and eslint, but I don't think that should be the case.

Comment: You are missing `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` in your devDependencies, which are required to lint TypeScript code with ESLint. See how to configure ESLint for TypeScript [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/)

Comment: Adding those changes the error slightly to "Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved"

Comment: You still need to update your ESLint config to use the new packages. See step #2 from the link I shared earlier